# Change specific line and row in text file in bash

Tags: bash, text-files

I have a text file like below

```
01 02 03 04 05
11 22 33 44 55
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
```

My text file has five rows and five columns which separated by space. now I decide to change the value in row #3 and column #4 (I mean 24) with 99.

It means that my output will be:

```
01 02 03 04 05
11 22 33 44 55
21 22 23 99 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
```

I appreciate if you kindly guide me

Sincerely

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR == 3 { $4 = 99 } { print }' data.in >data.out
```

The `awk` script will print every row, but if it finds row number three, it will first change the fourth value to 99.

Note: `NR` means "the ordinal number of the current record", not "row number", but since by default a record is a row, it's the same thing in this case.

Comment: or with variables: `awk -v row=3 -v col=4 'NR == row { $col = "99" } { print }' data.in >data.out`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to preserve blank lines between two lines then following should work.

```
awk 'NR==3 {$4=99}1' file
```

If you want to preserve blank line between two lines then following should work.

```
grep . file | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n"}NR==3{$4="99"}1'
01 02 03 04 05

11 22 33 44 55

21 22 23 99 25

31 32 33 34 35

41 42 43 44 45
```